# Heroku + Yii "Application runtime path is not valid"

Tags: php, web-applications, heroku, path, yii

I'm trying to deploy a Yii webapp into Heroku but, it keep throwing at me a weird error:

```
Application runtime path "/app/www/protected/runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process.
```

Makes no sense and I know is something to do with Heroku because in my local machine it works fine.
Does anyone what does this means? what do I need to do in Heroku ti fix this??
Many thanks.

Comment: Have you made sure that the runtime path (by default, the `runtime` folder inside the application's `protected` folder) exists and is writable by Yii? Have you checked that all the paths specified in the configuration are correct?

Comment: It is permission issue. make it writeable

Comment: Thanks for the comments. How can I be sure the folder is writeable ?

Comment: chmod 755 to your protected folder

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!
That solved it. It were actually two things: I needed the chmod and the fact the runtime folder wasn't committed in Heroku simply because the folder was empty so if it's empty it won't deploy to the server.

Anyhow, thanks.