# How to host an yii project in Heroku cloud platform?

Tags: php, heroku, yii, internal-server-error

Can any one explain how to host an yii project in heroku.

I have already tried and pushed my yii project into heroku.

But it is not loading and shows server error.

Comment: What's the error? More details are always helpful :-)

Comment: I tried to host my yii app on heroku.I dont know,whether I did it  in the correct way or not.I am a complete newbie in using heroku and git.After pushing my code,I got the app url. But it displays a blank page.Can you please give me in details how to host an yii app in heroku?Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to get your app setup so you can see debugging errors (YII_DEBUG in your index.php file).  You're probably running into permissions errors on the runtime folder.

See this for more details:
[Heroku + Yii "Application runtime path is not valid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770168/heroku-yii-application-runtime-path-is-not-valid)